# Generate and commit a file in the context of a post-receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

I need to create a git hook whose responsibility is to compile a handlebars file to .js after a push. So, for every new .hbs file pushed, I must generate a corresponding .js file and for every modified .hbs, I need to update the corresponding .js. The .js file must then be added and committed to the repo.

The requirements state that it HAS to be done server side, so I cannot use any client side hooks.

I am planning to use a post-receive hook to implement this scenario.
I am a not very experimented using git (and even less hooks), so my question is: how can I add a file and create a new commit in a bare repository (in the context of a post-receive hook) if I don't have the files tree?

Thanks!

Comment: I would expect your handlebars compiler needs a checked out source tree. So if you are in a bare repo, you might find it easiest to check out your repo to a temporary location, compile your stuff, commit and push back and delete the temporary repo again.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I am going to do. I was just wondering if there was a more idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: The most idiomatic way is not to store generated files in the repo at all but to generate them during deployment. The second most idiomatic way is to generate them at the client before committing. The stupid requirement to generate files at the server side leads to completely unidiomatic (idiotic) ways. Not your fault, I understand.